# AngularJS $http.post() to another port at the same machine

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, post, nginx

I have an AngularJS app hosted in nginx server at localhost and Rest service hosted in Weblogic at localhost:7001.

I'm trying to do this post inside of Angular part:

```
$http.post('localhost:7001/testApp/user/login', { username: username, password: password })
            .success(function (response) {
                callback(response);
});
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:7001/testApp/user/login. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Add the protocol scheme to the uri, eg: `http://localhost:7001/testApp/user/login`

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the protocol scheme (`http`, `https`, ...) in the URL:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:7001/testApp/user/login', { username: username, password: password })
        .success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
});
```